# Travel to Italy with Romanian Travel Document 1951

Tags: visas, refugees

I am a stateless person with a Romanian Travel Document 1951 for refugees. I want to go to Italy. I think I do not need a visa. I asked Embassy of Italy here and they told me it is OK without visa. I am afraid of being denied boarding to airplane or problems at check-in. I saw on this site many problems at check-in.

What advice can you give me to show I do not need visa if problems appear in the airport?

I don't want to miss my plane.